# parsing a Json Array in play framework JsObject

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following Json:

```
{
  "web-category" : "macaroons",
  "sub-categories" : [
     { "name" : "pink" },
     { "name" : "blue" },
     { "name" : "green" }
  ]

}
```

I have got it in Play as a JsObject. So I can now successfully do the following:

```
//(o is the JsObject)

val webCat:Option[String] = (o \ "web-category").asOpt[String]

println(webCat.toString)

>> Some(macaroons)
```

So far, so good. But how do I access the array Json objects? I have this...

```
val subCats:Option[JsArray] = (o \ "sub-categories").asOpt[JsArray]

println(subCats.toString)

>> Some([{"name" : "blue"},{"name" : "green"},{"name" : "pink"}])
```

but what I need is to take the JsArray and get a List of all the names something like this:

```
List("blue", "green", "pink")
```

Don't know how to access the JsArray thusly.

my thanks for your help in this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd argue that it's generally a good idea to move from JSON-land to native-Scala-representation-land as early as possible. If `obj` is your `JsObject`, for example, you can write this:

```
val subCategories = (obj \ "sub-categories").as[List[Map[String, String]]]

val names = subCategories.map(_("name"))
```

Or even:

```
case class Category(name: String, subs: List[String])

import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val categoryReader = (
  (__ \ "web-category").read[String] and
  (__ \ "sub-categories").read[List[Map[String, String]]].map(_.map(_("name")))
)(Category)
```

And then:

```
obj.as[Category]
```

This latter approach makes error handling even cleaner (e.g. you can just replace `as` with `asOpt` at this top level) and composes nicely with other `Reads` type class instances—if you have a `JsArray` of these objects, for example, you can just write `array.as[List[Category]]` and get what you expect.

Answer (score 12):

What Peter said, or:

```
(o \ "sub-categories" \\ "name").map(_.as[String]).toList
```

Comment: [EDIT] no I don't, my bad. I used 'sub-category' in actual fact, not 'sub-categories. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
subCats.map( jsarray => jsarray.value.map(jsvalue => (jsvalue \ "name").as[String]).toList)
```

This will normally return a `Option[List[String]]`